# Filter postgresql query where value is not a substring of any other value in the same column

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with a column called `values`:

```
values | other_columns...
-------+-----------------
     f |              ...
   foo |              ...
    fo |              ...
   bar |              ...
    ba |              ...
   baz |              ...
foobar |              ...
```

When querying this table I want to filter the results so that the only remaining rows are those in which `value` is not a substring of any other `value` in the column:

```
prime_values | other_result_columns...
-------------+------------------------
         baz |                     ...
      foobar |                     ...
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With NOT EXISTS:

```
select t.* 
from tablename t
where not exists (
  select 1
  from tablename
  where 
    values <> t.values 
    and 
    values like concat('%', t.values, '%')
)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=c075c9a126224532d2085c53369595b8).
Results:

```
> | values |...
> | :----- |
> | baz    |
> | foobar |
```